Unable to call a method in python class
I am trying to execute the following code but the last line of code is giving error.
I have method max_profit_assignment in Profile class and when i'm trying to execute it with profile object, it gives error.
class JOB:
    def __init__(self, job, profit):
        self.job = job
        self.profit = profit

class Profile:
    def max_profit_assignment(difficulty, profit, worker):
        jobs = [JOB(difficulty[i], profit[i]) for i in range(len(difficulty))]

        n = len(worker)
        i = 0
        current_profit = 0
        max_profit = 0

        for able in worker:
            while i < n:
                if jobs[i].job <= able:
                    current_profit = max(current_profit, jobs[i].profit)
                i += 1
            i = 0

            print(current_profit)
            max_profit += current_profit
            current_profit = 0

        return max_profit

if __name__ == "__main__":
    difficulty = [5, 50, 92, 21, 24, 70, 17, 63, 30, 53]
    profit = [68, 100, 3, 99, 56, 43, 26, 93, 55, 25]
    worker = [96, 3, 55, 30, 11, 58, 68, 36, 26, 1]
    profile = Profile()
    print(dir(profile))
    print(profile.max_profit_assignment(difficulty, profit, worker))

print(profile.max_profit_assignment(difficulty, profit, worker))
This line give error, why ?
  File "C:\Users\jerry\Downloads\GOLong\PythonCode\Profile.py", line 34, in <module>
    print(profile.max_profit_assignment(difficulty, profit, worker))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Profile.max_profit_assignment() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given


An ordinary class method will automatically be passed a first parameter that gives the instance the method is being called on (traditionally named self).  You didn't define any such parameter, thus the error.  Note that it was pointless to put this function in a class, it's not benefiting in any way.

This is because the method max_profit_assignment you are trying to call is an static method and the way you are trying to access it is like calling an instance method. For that you need to change the method signature, add self keyword to max_profit_assignment method then it will work fine.
   class Profile:
       def max_profit_assignment(self, difficulty, profit, worker):

add self as the first parameter in method signature.

self keyword makes a method to be accessible with class object. without self keyword the method becomes static method.

That's utterly wrong.  self isn't a keyword, it's just the traditional name for the first parameter of a method.  The way you make a static method is to put the @staticmethod decorator in front of it.
